# How to align text and image in a SliverGrid in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, grid-layout

I am using the SliverGrid feature to build my gridView. I trying to have the text placed below the image but the text isn't aligning with the image and its showing a `Bottom Overflowed` error. This is the code:

```
SliverPadding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          sliver: SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
            ),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GridTile(
                        child: Image.network(
                          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562176566-73c303ac1617?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Sammy the Pup',
                        style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                            color: kOrange, fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

And this is what the gridview looks like(Output of the above):
[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of `GridView` is determined by the `AspectRatio`

```
SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1 / 1,<---
          ),
```

As the `AspectRatio` gets smaller the height gets larger and as the ratio gets larger the heights gets smaller

Comment: what you mean is just reduce the crossAxisCount to 2,but there is 3 widget every row.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is three months old if you have a question please post a new question but no i did not mean `reduce the crossAxisCount to 2` I said what i meant the question was about how to adjust the height of a grid. So the `crossAxisCount` is irrelevant in my answer as I am only explaining to him how to adjust the height.

Comment: Sorry, I did't get it that time, because I saw the `crossAxisCount` numer is 2. Thank you, now I get it.

Comment: its okay no worries :)